# I need ezsurf to show me the top part of the graph, but I can't get it to

Tags: matlab, graph, surface

It's actually quite amusing.

Wolfram Alpha only shows me the [top part](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29%20%3D%201%2F%281-x%5E2-y%5E2%29) of the entire graph, [ezsurf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d09Hr.jpg) only wants to show me the bottom half of the graph, using a meshgrid yields [this ugly weirdness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY7aN.jpg), and changing the zlim on the ezsurf drawn graph gives me a [flat plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI0ua.jpg).

I'd like Matlab to show me something smooth and nice, like what ezsurf and wolfram are showing, but I'd like to see both parts of it in the same graph.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi @Kostoglotov so did you try any of the suggestions below?

Comment: I'm coming back to them soon, I found two solutions from a post I made to /r/Matlab that I have tried, http://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/2xet5e/i_need_ezsurf_to_show_me_the_top_part_of_the/cozn3qb?context=3 and http://www.reddit.com/r/matlab/comments/2xet5e/i_need_ezsurf_to_show_me_the_top_part_of_the/cozmvtm?context=3

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is just a matter of selecting the right x-and y coordinates to plot.

On Wolfram, both x and y go form -0.5 to 0.5. Doing so in Matlab gives the following:

```
clear
clc

[x,y] = meshgrid(-.5:.01:.5,-.5:.01:.5);

z = 1./(1-x.^2-y.^2);

surf(x,y,z,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','interp')

colormap(jet)
view(30,50);
camlight right
```

[image]

You can change the viewpoint of course but that looks nice to me :)

Answer (score 0):

set the limits you want to plot:

```
ezsurf(@f,[-.5,.5],[-.5,.5])
```

You may also want this:

```
function z=f(x,y)
z = 1./(1-x.^2-y.^2);
z(z<0)=nan;
end
```

Then plot using `ezsurf(@f,[-1,1],[-1,1],'circ')`:

[image]

```
ezsurf(@f,[-1,1],[-1,1],'circ')
```

or without `circ` option

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to see both (top and bottom parts) in the one graph.

Comment: Not with ezplot, extend the range in Benoit's solution